# Question about the proof that every linear operator from a finite dimensional normed space is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

There's this general proof you see about linear operators from finite dimensional normed spaces being bounded (or continuous) you can see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#A_linear_map_from_a_finite-dimensional_space_is_always_continuous).

I don't understand why we can say choose $M = \sup_{i}{\Vert f(e_{i})\Vert}$. How do we know that $\Vert f(e_{i}) \Vert \neq \infty$ for any $i$? Doesn't choosing $M$ in this manner already imply that $f$ is bounded, since the definition of boundedness is "$\exists c > 0$ such that $\Vert f(v) \Vert \leq c \Vert v \Vert$" (replace $c$ with $M$ and $v$ with $e_{i}$ and we're on the situation above).

Everything else I understand.

Comment: Note you're taking supremum of a finite set.

Comment: Keep in mind that in this context, "any $i$" is really just $i = 1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Yes I know that it's a supremum of a finite set but it doesn't really matter since on finite sets supremum coincides with maximum. By "any $i$" I meant "any $i = 1, \ldots, n$".

Comment: @unown Then what is your doubt. Once you know supremum is over a finite set, then $M$ is well-defined.

Comment: How do we know that $M < \infty$? That is what I don't understand and it's rather essential for $f$ to be bounded.

Comment: @unown Like you said, a finite set, in fact, contains its supremum and it's equal to the maximum.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I don't understand is how that supremum, or maximum, is not equal to $\infty$. How would I know that $\Vert f(e_{i}) \Vert \neq \infty$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$?

Answer (score 1):

I think I misunderstood your doubt. You seem to be asking why $\|f(e_i)\|<\infty$ for a particular $i.$ Note that $\|\cdot\|$ is a real-valued function and so $\|y\|<\infty$ for all $y \in Y.$ This has nothing to do with $f.$

Comment: Do you mean that there is no "infinity element" in $Y$? Because if so, then I can see how the finiteness of $X$ comes into play.

Comment: @unown What is infinity element?

Comment: Depends on the space. For example w.r.t. $\mathbb{R}$ it is the usual $\infty$, and w.r.t. $\mathbb{C}$ it's the complex infinity $\widetilde{\infty}$. However since here we have not specified what normed space $Y$ is I call $\infty_{Y}$ "infinity element of Y". With this definition do you mean that $f(e_{i}) \neq \infty_{Y} \not\in Y$ (as in $\infty\not\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\widetilde{\infty}\not\in\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: The is no such thing as $\infty \in \mathbb{R}.$ Even if $y\in Y =\mathbb{R}, y =\infty$ is an incorrect statement.